# Generating a feature vector for nodes and edges in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I want to create a `networkx` graph in which I have attributes for the nodes and also for the edges. I know that for each node and edge one can create a map/dictionary of attributes. However I need to create a feature vector for each node and each edge to use them with `scikit-learn` to train a classifier. I don't want to create an explicit features matrix where each row represents the features of a node. Rather I want to incorporate the feature vector in the `networkx` graph itself. So I want something like this:

```
node = Graph.get_node(i)
feature_vec = node.get_features_vector()
```

Is there a quick/pythonic way to do this without writing 'wrappers'?

Comment: You could do this by setting the feature vector as one of the attributes in the node attribute dict you mention.  However, I think you'll still need to convert it to a matrix for scikit, because scikit wants its input as numpy arrays.  So I'm not sure what you gain by not just making it a matrix in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a numpy array as a node attribute.  Something like,

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: G = nx.Graph()

In [4]: feature_vector=np.array([1,7,22])

In [5]: G.add_node(1,v=feature_vector)

In [6]: G.node[1]['v']
Out[6]: array([ 1,  7, 22])
```